# Table of content

Tags: html, css, xml

I want to create help for my application using Help and Manual 6.
I used arabic language in my H&M project, But the table of content is left side.
I want to place TOC in right side. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to move it to the right side, you can apply a style of `float: right`.

If you need the text direction to be right to left, you can set `direction: rtl;` on the TOC.

Comment: If your TOC has an id of toc, for example, like `<div id="toc">`, you just create the styles in your CSS file. `#toc { float: right; direction: rtl; }`

Comment: It's still in left side. :( Should I apply style just here?

Comment: It would help if you posted your HTML and existing CSS either in a jsfiddle or directly into your question. It's impossible to troubleshoot otherwise.